# Syntax error on token "System", delete this token - out cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, if-statement, syntax, while-loop, syntax-error

The answer is probably staring me in the face but I am unsure as to why I am receiving this error. I am receiving Syntax error on token "System" in my `if` `else` statements at the bottom of my code. All lines similar to line 131 onwards are receiving the error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Complete code so far;**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment3 {


static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileReader("AssistantHoursAndRates.txt"));

    double UnitRM1;
        System.out.println("Enter recommended maximum staff cost of Unit 1");
            UnitRM1 = console.nextDouble ();
                System.out.println("Recommended maximum staff cost of Unit1 = "+UnitRM1);

                System.out.printf("%10s\n", " ");

    double UnitRM2;
            System.out.println("Enter recommended maximum staff cost of Unit 2");
                UnitRM2 = console.nextDouble ();
                    System.out.println("Recommended maximum staff cost of Unit2 = "+UnitRM2);

                    System.out.printf("%10s\n", " ");

    double UnitRM3;
            System.out.println("Enter recommended maximum staff cost of Unit 3");       
                UnitRM3 = console.nextDouble ();        
                    System.out.println("Recommended maximum staff cost of Unit3 = "+UnitRM3);   

                    System.out.printf("%10s\n", " ");

    double UnitRM4;
            System.out.println("Enter recommended maximum staff cost of Unit 4");
                UnitRM4 = console.nextDouble ();
                    System.out.println("Recommended maximum staff cost of Unit4 = "+UnitRM4);   

                    System.out.printf("%10s\n", " ");

     double UnitRM5;            
             System.out.println("Enter recommended maximum staff cost of Unit 5");      
                UnitRM5 = console.nextDouble ();        
                    System.out.println("Recommended maximum staff cost of Unit5 = "+UnitRM5);   

                    System.out.printf("%10s\n", " ");

     double UnitRM6;            
             System.out.println("Enter recommended maximum staff cost of Unit 6");              
                UnitRM6 = console.nextDouble ();       
                    System.out.println("Recommended maximum staff cost of Unit6 = "+UnitRM6);

                    System.out.printf("%10s\n", " ");

     double UnitRM7;
             System.out.println("Enter recommended maximum staff cost of Unit 7");
                UnitRM7 = console.nextDouble ();
                    System.out.println("Recommended maximum staff cost of Unit7 = "+UnitRM7);

                    System.out.printf("%10s\n", " ");

     double UnitRM8;            
             System.out.println("Enter recommended maximum staff cost of Unit 8");      
                UnitRM8 = console.nextDouble ();        
                    System.out.println("Recommended maximum staff cost of Unit8 = "+UnitRM8);   

                    System.out.printf("%10s\n", " ");

     double UnitRM9;                
            System.out.println("Enter recommended maximum staff cost of Unit 9");               
               UnitRM9 = console.nextDouble ();     
                   System.out.println("Recommended maximum staff cost of Unit9 = "+UnitRM9);




    double[] totals = new double[9];        
    int unit = 1;
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);

        double total = 0;

        int assistants = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Number of Assistants " + assistants);
        System.out.println("Hours  Rate");
        System.out.println("------------");
        for (int i = 0; i < assistants; i++) {
            int hours = input.nextInt();
            System.out.print(hours + "     ");
            double rate = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.println(rate);               
            total += (hours * rate);
        }


System.out.println("Total cost of Unit " + unit + " is " + total);
System.out.println();   
totals[unit - 1] = total;
    unit++;



        if (input.hasNextLine()) {
            input.nextLine();
            input.next();



        } 


    }


        System.out.println("Comparisons are as follows;");       

        String fileName = "results.txt";
        try {
            PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(fileName);


            if (UnitRM1 < totals[0])
            outputStream.println(totals[0])
            System.out.println("Unit 1 total staff cost is less than recommended maximum staff cost!");

                else
                    System.out.println("Unit 1 total staff cost is more than recommended maximum staff cost!");


            if (UnitRM2 < totals[1])
            outputStream.println(totals[1])
            System.out.println("Unit 2 total staff cost is less than recommended maximum staff cost!");

                else
                    System.out.println("Unit 2 total staff cost is more than recommended maximum staff cost!");


            if (UnitRM3 < totals[2])
            outputStream.println(totals[2])
            System.out.println("Unit 3 total staff cost is less than recommended maximum staff cost!");

                else
                    System.out.println("Unit 3 total staff cost is more than recommended maximum staff cost!");


            if (UnitRM4 < totals[3])
            outputStream.println(totals[3])
            System.out.println("Unit 4 total staff cost is less than recommended maximum staff cost!");

                else
                    System.out.println("Unit 4 total staff cost is more than recommended maximum staff cost!");


            if (UnitRM5 < totals[4])
            outputStream.println(totals[4])
            System.out.println("Unit 5 total staff cost is less than recommended maximum staff cost!");

                else
                    System.out.println("Unit 5 total staff cost is more than recommended maximum staff cost!");


            if (UnitRM6 < totals[5])
            outputStream.println(totals[5])
            System.out.println("Unit 6 total staff cost is less than recommended maximum staff cost!");

                else
                    System.out.println("Unit 6 total staff cost is more than recommended maximum staff cost!");


            if (UnitRM7 < totals[6])
            outputStream.println(totals[6])
            System.out.println("Unit 7 total staff cost is less than recommended maximum staff cost!");

                else
                    System.out.println("Unit 7 total staff cost is more than recommended maximum staff cost!");


            if (UnitRM8 < totals[7])
            outputStream.println(totals[7])
            System.out.println("Unit 8 total staff cost is less than recommended maximum staff cost!");

                else
                    System.out.println("Unit 8 total staff cost is more than recommended maximum staff cost!");


            if (UnitRM9 < totals[8])
            outputStream.println(totals[8])
            System.out.println("Unit 9 total staff cost is less than recommended maximum staff cost!");

                else
                    System.out.println("Unit 9 total staff cost is more than recommended maximum staff cost!");





        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }


}
```

**Errors are as follows;**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
Syntax error on token "System", delete this token
out cannot be resolved or is not a field
Syntax error on token "System", delete this token
out cannot be resolved or is not a field
Syntax error on token "System", delete this token
out cannot be resolved or is not a field
Syntax error on token "System", delete this token
out cannot be resolved or is not a field
Syntax error on token "System", delete this token
out cannot be resolved or is not a field
Syntax error on token "System", delete this token
out cannot be resolved or is not a field
Syntax error on token "System", delete this token
out cannot be resolved or is not a field
Syntax error on token "System", delete this token
out cannot be resolved or is not a field
Syntax error on token "System", delete this token
out cannot be resolved or is not a field

at Assignment3.main(Assignment3.java:131)
```

Line 131 is;

```
System.out.println("Unit 1 total staff cost is less than recommended maximum staff cost!");
```

Comment: Youre missing a bunch of braces `{}`

Comment: You are missing the semicolon on the previous line before the `System.out.println` call.

Comment: Your also importing java.lang.* which is redundant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your

```
    if (UnitRM2 < totals[0])
    outputStream.println(totals[0])
    System.out.println("Unit 1 total staff cost is less than recommended maximum staff cost!");

        else
```

to

```
    if (UnitRM1 < totals[0]){// place code in block {...}
        outputStream.println(totals[0]);// don't forget to add semicolon
        System.out.println("Unit 1 total staff cost is less than recommended maximum staff cost!");
    }
        else
```

Also little advice: start using IDE like Eclipse and use its tools to properly format your code. It is very hard to read now and simple <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> makes it lot easier to work with code.